# Deploy gradle project to remote server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gradle

I have gradle project in windows and I want to deploy it into tomcat in remote server (Ubuntu in vmware).

Can anyone help me how can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get the war file that you will need to place in the webapp dir from gradle build with `<project with war plugin>.war.outputs`

Then use this plugin: https://gradle-ssh-plugin.github.io/ to move the war file over. and execute command on the vm that starts tomcat.

I'll come back and update this answer with more details when I get the chance but hopefully this will point you in the right direction. I'm using a similar setup right now but it's been awhile since I made it.